# Login com Sha256

Tags: php, login, sha-256

Boa tarde a todos,

tenho um problema que me tem intrigado já a uns dias para cá, o meu chefe e orientador de estagio propôs-me para fazer uma segurança acrescida no site e para isso teria de usar um Hash de palavras passes, depois de muita investigação não consegui fazer login nas contas previamente "encriptadas" e não encontro maneira de encontrar o meu problema .

Página de registo

```
include("connect.php");

function generateSalt(){
  $characters = '0123456789abcdef';
  $length = 64; 

  $string = '';
  for ($max = mb_strlen($characters) - 1, $i = 0; $i < $length; ++ $i)
  {
    $string .= mb_substr($characters, mt_rand(0, $max), 1);
  }
  return $string;
}


$userAccountInput = $_POST['userName'];
$userPasswordInput = $_POST['pass'];
$salt = generateSalt();
$hash = hash_hmac("sha256", $userPasswordInput, $salt);

$sql = "INSERT INTO username VALUES (NULL,'$userAccountInput','$salt','$hash');"; 

$resultado = mysql_query ($sql);
```

Página de Login

```
function testPassword($fPassword, $fSaltFromDatabase, $fHashFromDatabase){
              if (hash_hmac("sha256", $fPassword, $fSaltFromDatabase) === $fHashFromDatabase){
                  return(true);
                  }else{
                  return(false);
  }
  }


function SignIn() 
{ 
//session_start(); 
if(!empty($_POST['userName']) || !empty($_POST['pass'])) 
{

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM username where userName = '".$_POST['userName']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

                //$userAccountInput = $_POST['userName'];
                $userPasswordInput = $_POST['pass'];
                $saltFromDatabase = $row['salt'];
                $hashFromDatabase = $row['hash'];

                $var_dump($row);

                if(testPassword($userPasswordInput, $saltFromDatabase, $hashFromDatabase)){
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('LOGIN COM SUCESSO!')</script>";
                    header('Location: ./clientes.php');
                }else{

                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('LOGIN FALHADO!')</script>";     
                }               



}

} 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        { 
            SignIn(); 
        } 
?>
```

Estou a ficar extramamente frustrado pois já estou a cerca de 5 dias a mudar o código e não encontro solução para este problema, espero bem que possam ajudar, qualquer ajudar é bem vinda e bastante agradecida, muito obrigado a todos.

Comment: A função `mysql_query` deve receber apenas uma `SQL query` como uma string. Você tá enviando `or die(mysql_error())` como parâmetro da função também, sendo que provavelmente não deveria ser assim.

Comment: Sim tem razão, já formatei o código para tal, mas mesmo assim o erro se mantém.

Comment: O `$_POST[username]` como `string` é normal no PHP? Não deveria ser separado da `string` com um `+`? Algo como `"SELECT * FROM username WHERE userName = " + $_POST[username]`

Comment: Eu pelo menos no resto do meu código nunca inseri o "+" e sempre funcionou, estava-me sim a faltar as '', agora já não me aparece erro a fazer login, mas não devolve o echo de "Sucesso" ou de "Falhado", a página simplesmente fica em branco

Comment: Onde está o código de execução da *query* de inserção?

Comment: Obrigado já consegui fazer o registo na base de dados usando este código de execução `$resultado = mysql_query ($sql);` , mas o login ainda não funciona

Comment: Não deverias pegar `$saltFromDatabase = $row['salt'];`? Não entendi porque está pegando do `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Eu usei o `$_REQUEST` para ir buscar a base de dados o valor, modifiquei para a sua opção mas o resultado continua o mesmo.

Comment: Verificou se os dados foram inseridos no banco de forma correta? Suas funções estão funcionando tudo certo: https://ideone.com/ALapd7

Comment: substitua `$_POST[userName]` por `$_POST['userName']`... Faltam as `aspas`

Comment: Sim o registo já funciona de forma correta, quando eu crio uma conta guarda na base de dados o `$userName` `$salt` e o `$hash`, mas quando faço login, a página fica em branco e não me devolve nenhum dos echo's que eu fiz

Comment: Eu substitui como aconcelhou, mas devolveu-me este erro _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\insysupgrades\login.php on line 20_

Comment: `$_POST[\"username\"]`, tem que escapar as aspas.

Comment: mesmo dessa forma, devolve-me o mesmo erro que abocado

Comment: Pode fazer um `var_dump($row)` e editar incluindo na sua pergunta? PS: altere a query para: `"SELECT * FROM username where userName = '".$_POST['userName']."'"`

Comment: Já alterei a query para o que me disse, e inseri o `var_dump($row);` mas não me devolve nada ;